# How can I get the text of the 1st label inside of a grid in CS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML code:

```
<ViewCell >
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  x:Name="abc" Tapped="atiSelectValueX" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding [0].Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="x" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

and this CS:

```
void atiSelectValueX(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var grid = sender as Grid;
   if (grid == null)
      return;

   var label = grid.Children. << trying to get the Text value
```

Can someone show me how I can get the value of the text for the first label? I tried some ideas using LINQ and getting the First or using a Where but for each I tried I still was not able to add .Text as I think somehow I need to cast the value to being a label so I can use label.Text

Comment: I just showed you how to do this?  Is this cell inside of a ListView?  Is there a reason you are using the Tapped event on the grid instead of the ListView's Tapped/Selected methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test it via the `is` statement:

```
var label = grid.Children.FirstOrDefault(_ => _ is Label) as Label;
var textValue = label?.Text;
```

Update: Or use Linq's `OfType<T>` (thanks to @Cheesebaron for the comment)

```
var label = grid.Children.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @Cheesebaron You are absolutely correct, I could blame the lack of coffee or the fact that I personally tend to avoid Linq and generics with ever possible when coding against Xamarin mobile platforms, but yes they are equivalent, different expression trees would be generated, ignoring the extra code for generics and the fact OfType is returning all Labels types, but FirstOrDefault is being used to short-circuit the enumeration anyway, the difference in Jit'd or AOT'd IL should be a wash... ( that is an assumption, I have not reviewed the AOT'd IL of a TypeOf expression tree :-/ )